# MySQL - Capital first letter of each word

Tags: mysql

Below is MySQL function to capitalize the first letter of every word in a string.

```
  USE `db`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `UC_Words`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `UC_Words`(str VARCHAR(255) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET latin1
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN   
DECLARE c CHAR(1);  
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(255);  
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;  
  DECLARE BOOL INT DEFAULT 1;  
  DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT ' ()[]{},.-_!@;:?/';  
  SET s = LCASE( str );  
  WHILE i < LENGTH( str ) DO  
     BEGIN  
       SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );  
       IF LOCATE( c, punct ) > 0 THEN  
        SET BOOL = 1;  
      ELSEIF BOOL=1 THEN  
        BEGIN  
          IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN  
             BEGIN  
               SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));  
               SET BOOL = 0;  
             END;  
           ELSEIF c >= '0' AND c <= '9' THEN  
            SET BOOL = 0;  
          END IF;  
        END;  
      END IF;  
      SET i = i+1;  
    END;  
  END WHILE;  
  RETURN s;  

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

It's works fine for all Strings. But if I provide string  "M R E" then its give "M R e" output.

plz suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First execute below query

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `UC_FIRST`(oldWord VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
RETURN CONCAT(UCASE(SUBSTRING(oldWord, 1, 1)),SUBSTRING(oldWord, 2))
```

Then execute below query

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `UC_Words`(oldName VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(1), trimSpaces BOOL) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    SET @oldString := oldName;
    SET @newString := "";

    tokenLoop: LOOP
    IF trimSpaces THEN SET @oldString := TRIM(BOTH " " FROM @oldString); END IF;

    SET @splitPoint := LOCATE(delim, @oldString);

    IF @splitPoint = 0 THEN
      SET @newString := CONCAT(@newString, UC_FIRST(@oldString));
      LEAVE tokenLoop;
    END IF;

    SET @newString := CONCAT(@newString, UC_FIRST(SUBSTRING(@oldString, 1, @splitPoint)));
    SET @oldString := SUBSTRING(@oldString, @splitPoint+1);
    END LOOP tokenLoop;

    RETURN @newString;
END
```

Then after call function

```
SELECT UC_Words("this is for testing"," ", TRUE);
```

Output below

```
This Is For Testing
```